# MySQL distinct count if conditions unique

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I am trying to build a query that tells me how many distinct women and men there are in a given dataset. The person is identified by a number 'tel'. It is possible for the same 'tel' to appear multiple times, but that 'tel's gender should only be counted one time!

7136609221 - male
7136609222 - male
7136609223 - female
7136609228 - male
7136609222 - male
7136609223 - female

This example_dataset would yield the following.
Total unique gender count: 4
Total unique male count: 3
Total unique female count: 1

My attempted query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tel, gender) as gender_count, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT tel, gender = 'male') as man_count, 
       SUM(if(gender = 'female', 1, 0)) as woman_count 
FROM example_dataset;
```

There's actually two attempts in there. `COUNT(DISTINCT tel, gender = 'male') as man_count` seems to just return the same as `COUNT(DISTINCT tel, gender)` -- it doesn't take into account the qualifier there. And the `SUM(if(gender = 'female', 1, 0))` counts all the female records, but is not filtered by DISTINCT tels.

Comment: What are you getting as an answer when you run this?

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT tel, gender = 'male')` gives man_count = 4 wrongly; it should be 3 -- unique per tel.

Comment: SUM(if(gender = 'female', 1, 0)) gives woman_count = 2, wrongly. It should be 1 (unique per tel)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Here's one option using a subquery with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) gender_count,
   SUM(IF(gender='male',1,0)) male_count,
   SUM(IF(gender='female',1,0)) female_count
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT tel, gender
   FROM example_dataset
) t
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc06f/1)

---

This will also work if you don't want to use a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tel) gender_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN gender = 'male' THEN tel END) male_count,  
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN gender = 'female' THEN tel END) female_count
FROM example_dataset
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc06f/9)

Comment: `DISTINCT CASE WHEN gender = 'male' THEN tel END` worked perfect. It was the solution I was looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ) was also exactly what i was looking for, thanks alot.

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN) worked for me. Thank You So Much.

Comment: Why does the second example use `CASE WHEN` instead of `IF()`?

Answer (score 11):

There is another solution similar to @segeddes's second solution

```
Select COUNT(DISTINCT tel) as gender_count, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT IF(gender = "male", tel, NULL)) as male_count, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT IF(gender = "female", tel, NULL)) as female_count 
FROM example_dataset
```

Explanation :

```
IF(gender = "male", tel, NULL)
```

Above expression will return tel if gender is male else it will return NULL value

Then we've

```
DISTINCT
```

It will remove all the duplicates

And finally

```
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(gender = "male", tel, NULL))
```

Will count all the distinct occurrences of rows having male gender

Note : SQL COUNT function with expression only counts rows with non NULL values,
for detailed explanation check - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/