# How to add where inside DB::raw() in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm want to get the `completed` orders amount, and the `rejected` orders count in 1 query. Please see my code below. How can I add where  or condition inside the DB::raw()?

```
return DB::table('restaurants')
->join('orders', 'restaurants.id', 'orders.restaurant_id')
->select([
   DB::raw('SUM(orders.total) WHERE status = 8 as completed_sum'),
   DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT(orders.transaction_code)) WHERE status = 3 as rejected_count')
])
->get();
```

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

**Update**

When I try `->toSql()`, I get this:

```
select `restaurant_name` as `restaurant`, SUM(total) WHERE status = 8 as completed_sum,
COUNT(DISTINCT(transaction_code)) WHERE status = 3 as rejected_count from `restuarants` inner join `orders` on
`restuarants`.`id` = `orders`.`restaurant_id` where `orders`.`date` between ? and ? group by `restuarants`.`id`
```

Comment: What is the output when you change `->get()` to `->sql()` and dump it ?

Comment: @Mike Please see my update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

id didn't got the chance to test it ... but it supposed to work

```
->select([
   DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN status = 8 THEN orders.total END) completed_sum'),
   DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT IF(status = 3,orders.transaction_code,null)) as rejected_count')
])
```

for sum with condition see:[mysql sum](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/)

for count with distinct with if see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58858732/10573560)